# Qt5 application silently exits on another machine

Tags: c++, windows, qt

When I try to run my application on another machine, where Qt SDK is not installed, it silently exits.

Now, if it were missing a DLL, Windows would show a message box like this, and I would put the DLL:

[image]

But I've already installed all the DLLs indicated by this type of message boxes. Besides, those message boxes happen on my machine, as well, until I put the DLLs in the same directory as the application.

Now the program just exits, no message boxes, and it exits only on other machines where Qt SDK is not installed.

This happens only when compiling with Qt5, same program compiled with Qt4 runs fine on the other machine where the Qt5 program fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some more digging I found out what the problem is - Qt5 also needs platform plugins, with the interesting twist that the application will silently fail on another machine, without any error message.

Also, those plugins can't be in the same directory as the EXE, they have to be in their own sub-directories.

It seems I need only one plugin:

```
platforms/qwindows.dll
```

Where the `platforms` directory is placed in the exe's directory.